# issue in position:fixed tablets only

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad, tablet

the site that I'm talking about is [here](http://174.137.191.60/~artancoi/).

We Have a very strange issue that we see only in tablets.

We use the [scroll to fixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) jQuery plugin to add position fixes to the sidebar after scroll and its work great in all devices, but only in tablets when you scroll fast the sidebar disappeared for a moment and after appearing again, 
if you scroll slowly its ok.
it's little hard to explain, but you can see it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4679964/Slack%20for%20iOS%20Upload.mp4)

its happen in safari and chrome too

i thought that maybe it's something on this plugin so i send to client more links of plugins that make this trick like this:

http://yckart.github.io/jquery.fixer.js/

http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/

http://www.directlyrics.com/code/lockfixed/demo.html

http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-Stickem/

but its happen in all this plugins so i think that maybe it's something on iPad or Tablets...

somebody know this issue? what the solution for "scroll to fixed" effect in Tablets?

Answer (score 1):

From: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/08/19/onscroll-event-issues-on-mobile-browsers/

These mobile browsers simply do not fire the onscroll event until scrolling has completely stopped. This includes not only the touch based scrolling itself, but additionally any momentum that the user gives on the scroll. The event will not fire until it stops. This is a problem if you want to apply a visual change to the screen as the user scrolls.

Comment: thanks ika -  there is some solution for this in this blog post?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a solution, but more like some workarounds.